# GenerateDSYMFile warning: unable to open object file

Tags: xcode, build-error

The background:
I have a project that I last built on 10.5 on a PPC computer using xcode v3.1. It builds against the 10.4 SDK. I now have a MacBook with 10.6 on it and Xcode v3.2.1. I installed the 10.4 SDK with xcode. So now I want to build the project on an intel chip on 10.6. I first get a build error because I have the wrong version of gcc setup so I change the build settings to use gcc 4.0.

The problem:
Now when I build the project I get the following warning:
GenerateDSYMFile "build/Release/What's Keeping Me?.app.dSYM" "build/Release/What's Keeping Me?.app/Contents/MacOS/What's Keeping Me?"
cd "/Users/hmcshane/Development/ Cocoa Projects/What's Keeping Me?"
/Developer/usr/bin/dsymutil "/Users/hmcshane/Development/ Cocoa Projects/What's Keeping Me?/build/Release/What's Keeping Me?.app/Contents/MacOS/What's Keeping Me?" -o "/Users/hmcshane/Development/ Cocoa Projects/What's Keeping Me?/build/Release/What's Keeping Me?.app.dSYM"

warning: (i386) /Users/hmcshane/Downloads/Csu-71/crt.dynamic_no_pic.o unable to open object file
warning: (ppc7400) /Users/hmcshane/Downloads/Csu-71/crt.dynamic_no_pic.o unable to open object file

Any idea what this is? And why is the path for the problem files rooted in my downloads folder? The project certainly doesn't reside there.

Comment: Have you done a "Clean All" on the project?

Comment: Hi Rob, yes I have... many times. I do a clean-all then I even delete the build folder before rebuilding the project.

Answer (score 34):

I see the annoyed warnings after upgrading to Xcode 4.5. Then I tried changing Build Settings/Debug Information Format value from **DWARF with dSYM file** to **DWARF** and every relative warning disappeared :)

Comment: If you have any problems with debugging allocation memory, change it back. The details could be found here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13580883/how-to-clear-abandoned-memory-that-doesnt-point-to-own-code/13794854#13794854

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue on iPhone, when building a projet that linked against custom static libraries. I seems XCode complains because it can't find debug infos for some of the linked objects.

I fixed the problem by **disabling "Perfom Single-Object Prelink"** in the library build settings.

I don't know how well this solution applies to the initial issue, but as this page is the first Google answer…

Comment: Kemenaran, thanks for the answer. I solved my problem another way. I am now using the 10.5 SDK as the base SDK to build my project but I made the "Deployment Target" 10.4. So my project will run on 10.4 still but it uses 10.5 SDK to build it. This solved my error. So there's something about the 10.4 SDK in XCode v 3.2 that doesn't show when using the 10.5 SDK. However, I'll keep your response in mind as I build other projects. I have others that I haven't gotten to yet on this machine so I'll probably see this error again. Thanks.

Comment: I saw this error in a test application for a framework after upgrading to Xcode 6.  I'm building a .framework for distribution to other developers.  This fixed it for me.

Answer (score 6):

If anyone gets this when building a C command line app in Xcode and is experimenting with cutting edge settings: I got this very same warning when I switched to Clang and enabled Link-Time Optimization (LLVM_LTO = YES) just for the fun of it.

Comment: Thnak you so much for this post.  I finally fixed my problem!!

Answer (score 5):

This may also be caused by **GENERATE_DEBUGGING** flag turned on. Turning that flag off in project or target settings will also work.

Comment: For me it was    

`GCC_GENERATE_DEBUGGING_SYMBOLS = NO` 

and

`GCC_SYMBOLS_PRIVATE_EXTERN = YES`.