# How to clear abandoned memory that doesn't point to own code?

Tags: ios, instruments, abandoned-memory

It seems that my app is abandoning memory since the persistent memory of recorded heapshots don't fall to zero and the heap continue to grow when the same set of operations are continuously repeated:
[image]

To find out the problems, many people suggest [Bill's site](http://www.friday.com/bbum/2010/10/17/when-is-a-leak-not-a-leak-using-heapshot-analysis-to-find-undesirable-memory-growth/) that is not useful for me since I am using ARC, whereas he points to reference issues. I then followed [Apple docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#recipes/instruments_help-memory-allocations-help/Finding_Abandoned_Memory/07_Finding_Abandoned_Memory.html) and watched some videos relating to abandoned memory from the WWDCs. They all say that instruments will help to point to the line of code that might cause the problems. So I reviewed every single object but didn't see anything relating to my code:

[image]

Comment: better recheck your codes to find where is the memory leak is occuring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that changing **Build Settings\Build Options\Debug Information Format** from **DWARF** to **DWARF with dSYM File** will fix the problem.

[image]

Comment: Except for the the title, I don't think it's very clear that this was your problem, also all answers seem to try to answer how to tackle the memory issues, not about (re)symbolication issues...

Comment: After changing this setting, the instrument tool points to my own code. So I could find the root causes.

Comment: when changing Build Settings\Build Options\Debug Information Format from DWARF to DWARF with dSYM File ,did the dsym file will lost ? and than crash file cannot covert to human file ?

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to look explicitly for retain cycles. When in hierarchy you have a parent object object that has related object and both have strong type of proprties, they will never get released from memory.

Quick example:

```
@interface Parent : NSObject
@property (strong) Child *child;
@end
@interface Child : NSObject
@property (strong) Parent *parent;
@end
```

Also by default properties are strong, so it is the same if you do not declare it at all.

The way it should be:

```
@interface Parent : NSObject
@property (strong) Child *child;
@end
@interface Child : NSObject
@property (weak) Parent *parent;
@end
```

I also found information that Instruments can show you retain cycles (and it looks nice). More details here [How to activate Cycles reporting in Instruments under ARC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8852451/how-to-activate-cycles-reporting-in-instruments-under-arc) However I don't know if it works with ARC, comments may suggest it does not. As a cumbersome way I can recommend commenting out some code you feel may be responsible and then check the picture.

---

So that's for the retain cycles. Another thing you should look for is when you allocate memory that ARC is not able to return. Those calls are looking like C functions and by convention have a word Create in the name. Each time you make such a pointer then you should also clean after yourself. Just to give you some examples:

- CGColorCreate - CGColorRelease
- CGColorSpaceCreateWithName - CGColorSpaceRelease
- CGBitmapContextCreate - CGContextRelease

As you can see each function has it's corresponding releasing function which usually you should be able to find in documentation.

Comment: Apple also describes retain cycles here https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmPractical.html

Comment: Thanks ride.inc, I found 1 retain cycle in my app. After fixed, the heap growth reduced a little bit, not all. Is there anything else could be the cause of the problem?

Comment: Sure, I just updated the answer with Create() functions that should follow release after, maybe you have some of those.

Comment: I don't use such function, try searching with 'Create' keyword in my project but see nothing

Comment: Then maybe you can try to comment out code pieces "recursively". Like first comment out alomost all the code and then if you run and test the app it obviously should work fine. Then enable only small piece of code, check, enable another module/lines, check. This should point more or less to the place that is responsible. If you give that info then I can help you further.

Comment: This might be the final solution since it will take time. I will do it during review period.

Answer (score 0):

Or you are testing with Zombies turned on (edit scheme - diagnostics). If zombies are turned on, they are never deleted and thus memory always grows.

Comment: Thanks ahwulf, I did check Diagnostics/ Objective-C - Enable Zombie Objects is unchecked. So, it might be not the cause.