# error: unable to open executable ''

Tags: xcode

I just ran into this issue with my Xcode project:

whenever I run it, it says there is the following error `GenerateDSYMFile /Users/obleopold/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/richhh-bzvkjxyolcsbhoffzrtzyohyzhye/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/richhh.app.dSYM /Users/obleopold/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/richhh-bzvkjxyolcsbhoffzrtzyohyzhye/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/richhh.app/richhh
    cd /Users/obleopold/Documents/richhh
    setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/dsymutil /Users/obleopold/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/richhh-bzvkjxyolcsbhoffzrtzyohyzhye/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/richhh.app/richhh -o /Users/obleopold/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/richhh-bzvkjxyolcsbhoffzrtzyohyzhye/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/richhh.app.dSYM`

The main issue states:
`error: unable to open executable ''`

Here is some more info:
My project name is: `richhh`,
my computer username is: `obleopold`

If you need any more information, please comment.

Comment: try
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8746194/unable-to-open-executable-xcode
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2453206/generatedsymfile-warning-unable-to-open-object-file

Answer (score 0):

Go to Product->Clean and then Product->Clean builds(option comes by pressing option button). Delete the derived data, restart Xcode and try running